# Not able to Create Contact flow with lex bot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

Trying to migrate contact flow from one instance to other able to migrate simple flow but issue is when I tried with lex bot not able to migrate contact flow.

```
aws connect describe-contact-flow --instance-id <value> --contact-flow-id <value> --region us-east-1
aws connect create-contact-flow --instance-id <value> --name test_flow --type AGENT_TRANSFER --region  'us-east-1' --content "{\"Version\":\"2019-10-30\",\"StartAction\":\"cd60c6aa-6229-4a47-81ae-bef78a528590\",\"Metadata\":{\"entryPointPosition\":{\"x\":15,\"y\":23.99998474121091},\"snapToGrid\":false,\"ActionMetadata\":{\"bbb8a214-1f5c-4534-bfe5-6bf5f0aab9a0\":{\"position\":{\"x\":685,\"y\":132}},\"d76376f8-9b97-42dc-8b96-60167fd5f7a2\":{\"position\":{\"x\":351,\"y\":15}},\"cd60c6aa-6229-4a47-81ae-bef78a528590\":{\"position\":{\"x\":194,\"y\":197.3333282470703},\"useDynamic\":false},\"e36919ca-8fe7-4797-8c7e-6524acd838f8\":{\"position\":{\"x\":446,\"y\":208},\"conditionMetadata\":[],\"useDynamic\":false,\"dynamicMetadata\":{},\"useLexBotDropdown\":true,\"useDynamicLexBotArn\":false,\"lexV2BotName\":\"jenkinsbooktrip\"}}},\"Actions\":[{\"Identifier\":\"bbb8a214-1f5c-4534-bfe5-6bf5f0aab9a0\",\"Type\":\"DisconnectParticipant\",\"Parameters\":{},\"Transitions\":{}},{\"Identifier\":\"d76376f8-9b97-42dc-8b96-60167fd5f7a2\",\"Parameters\":{\"FlowLoggingBehavior\":\"Enabled\"},\"Transitions\":{\"NextAction\":\"bbb8a214-1f5c-4534-bfe5-6bf5f0aab9a0\",\"Errors\":[],\"Conditions\":[]},\"Type\":\"UpdateFlowLoggingBehavior\"},{\"Identifier\":\"cd60c6aa-6229-4a47-81ae-bef78a528590\",\"Parameters\":{\"Text\":\"hi welcome\"},\"Transitions\":{\"NextAction\":\"e36919ca-8fe7-4797-8c7e-6524acd838f8\",\"Errors\":[],\"Conditions\":[]},\"Type\":\"MessageParticipant\"},{\"Identifier\":\"e36919ca-8fe7-4797-8c7e-6524acd838f8\",\"Parameters\":{\"Text\":\"welcome\",\"LexBot\":{\"Name\":\"jenkinsbooktrip\",\"Region\":\"us-east-1\",\"Alias\":\"$LATEST\"}},\"Transitions\":{\"NextAction\":\"bbb8a214-1f5c-4534-bfe5-6bf5f0aab9a0\",\"Errors\":[{\"NextAction\":\"bbb8a214-1f5c-4534-bfe5-6bf5f0aab9a0\",\"ErrorType\":\"NoMatchingError\"},{\"NextAction\":\"d76376f8-9b97-42dc-8b96-60167fd5f7a2\",\"ErrorType\":\"NoMatchingCondition\"}],\"Conditions\":[]},\"Type\":\"ConnectParticipantWithLexBot\"}]}"
```

An error occurred (InvalidContactFlowException) when calling the CreateContactFlow operation: None,
when trying without lex parameter it working fine able to create but with lex its through an error I am using aws cli command

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue generally with connect. When the content is less than ~1500-2000 characters, the Api works perfectly. Once the contact flow content grows beyond that, you start getting those errors.

Comment: Issue is due to Alias name with $LATEST , Need to escape $ symbol.Alias without $ its working fyn for me

Answer (score -1):

Yes that's right need to skip $ symbol and it will work fine.